# how to run python script as a service in Linux

Tags: python, linux, service

I have a python script that I would like to be used as a service in Suse Linux.

I tried creating a script.conf file in /etc/init.d that looks like this:

```
description "File service"
author  "Me"

start on runlevel [234]
stop on runlevel [0156]

chdir /app/file/bin
exec /app/file/bin/script.py
respawn
```

How do I test if this script is working ? I have no idea what command to type to start running this service. Any answers to this will be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: http://superuser.com/ may be a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

**Lets break answer in two parts first how to configure it and Second how to run and test it as process.**

How to configure?

Configuration you have posted above is correct. But file is supposed to be created under directory /etc/init/myscript-service.conf (That's what I follow in my scenario). 
Another configuration part is you have to make script file executable so that it can run as service.

Linux command

```
chmod u+x /app/file/bin/script.py
```

You need to add below line in your python script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

And install upstart tool.

After above all configuration you are ready to run script as service.

How to run and test?

Once you have created file myscript-service.conf you can start the service as normal service in linux using below command.

```
service myscript-service start
```

It will give you process id. And you can start/stop/status it like normal service.

Logs you can find under

/var/log/upstart/myscript-service.log